# How to get command line parameters in a WPF application using MvvmCross?

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, mvvmcross, app-startup

I'm trying to get command line parameters passed to my WPF application using MvvmCross.
I want to access the parameters in my MainViewModel.

Similar to how you would override the OnStartup() method (or create an event handler for the Startup event) in the `App.xaml.cs` and do stuff with your parameters there.

I tried inheriting my `App.cs` from `MvxApplication<object>` and using `MvxNavigationViewModel<object>` as the MainViewModel base class like so:

```c#
public class App : MvxApplication<object>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        #region BulkRegistration

        CreatableTypes()
            .EndingWith("Service")
            .AsInterfaces()
            .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

        #endregion

        #region AppStartRegistration

        RegisterAppStart<MainViewModel, object>();

        #endregion
    }
}
```

The `Prepare(object parameter)` method in my MainViewModel never gets called though.

```c#
public class MainViewModel : MvxNavigationViewModel<object>
{
    // ...

    public override void Prepare(object parameter)
    {
        // do stuff with parameter
    }
}
```

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: Does `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` give you what you need?

Comment: @RyanThomas Actually... yes! Retarded me. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, I'll post an answer just so you can accept and the question is complete :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the following regardless of whether you are in a ViewModel or where ever you are.

```
var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```